# How to sort a List by checking a value inside inner list in Java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class like the following,

```
public class Inventory {

   private String name;
   private List<Sample> samples;
}

public class Sample {

   private int count;
   private String date;
}

List<Inventory> inventories;
```

I have sorted the `samples` by date. It's fine. But I need to sort the `inventories` list by `date` field inside Sample class. `samples` are already sorted. So I need the inventories to sort by samples date DESC. For example,

Inside that `inventories` list, if it has 3 data,

```
Inventory 1
name = 1
samples has dates of = List of (2021-07-02, 2021-07-03)

Inventory 2
name = 2
samples has dates of = List of (2021-07-02, 2021-09-03, 2021-10-03)

Inventory 3
name = 3
samples has dates of = List of (2021-08-02, 2021-09-03)
```

So it should sort by date DESC and in that `inventories` list, it should have the data following way,

```
Inventory 1
Inventory 3
Inventory 2
```

Comment: How should the inventories be sorted based on sample dates?  Do you want to use the earliest or latest sample date for each inventory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with the `Comparable` interface.

I have assumed that the `Sample` objects are sorted by date and `Inventory` objects are sorted by comparing the last (`Sample` with latest date) `Sample` in `samples`, but you can implement your own custom comparing logic in `Sample`s overridden `compareTo()` method.

```java
  public class Inventory implements Comparable<Inventory> {

    private String name;
    private List<Sample> samples;

    public List<Sample> getSamples() {
      return samples;
    }

    public Inventory(String name, List<Sample> samples) {
      this.name = name;
      this.samples = samples;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Inventory inventory) {
      Optional<Sample> thisOldestSample = this.getSamples().stream().sorted().reduce((s1, s2) -> s2);
      Optional<Sample> thatOldestSample = inventory.getSamples().stream().sorted().reduce((s1, s2) -> s2);

      if (thisOldestSample.isPresent() && thatOldestSample.isPresent()) {
        return thisOldestSample.get().compareTo(thatOldestSample.get());
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }

  public class Sample implements Comparable<Sample> {

    private int count;
    private String date;

    public String getDate() {
      return date;
    }

    public Sample(int count, String date) {
      this.count = count;
      this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Sample sample) {
      return LocalDate.parse(sample.getDate()).isBefore(LocalDate.parse(this.getDate())) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }

  @Test
  void shouldSortInventoriesBasedOnSampleDate() {
    Inventory one = new Inventory("1", List.of(new Sample(0, "2021-07-02"), new Sample(1, "2021-07-03")));
    Inventory two = new Inventory("2", List.of(new Sample(0, "2021-07-02"), new Sample(1, "2021-09-03"), new Sample(2, "2021-10-03")));
    Inventory three = new Inventory("3", List.of(new Sample(0, "2021-08-02"), new Sample(1, "2021-09-03")));

    List<Inventory> unsorted  = List.of(one, two, three);
    List<Inventory> sorted = unsorted.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

    assertEquals(one, sorted.get(0));
    assertEquals(three, sorted.get(1));
    assertEquals(two, sorted.get(2));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also for your time.

Answer (score 5):

You want to sort collections based on the values in nested collections.
How do we do it?

You need to implement a custom comparator to do this ...

```java
static class InventoryComparator implements Comparator<Inventory> {
     public int compare(Inventory i1, Inventory i2) {
         // compare them here like this 
         // a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.
         // this can be done by checking the nested lists
     }
}
```

Then you can sort your collection like this ...

```java
Collections.sort(inventoryList, new InventoryComparator());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also for your time.